# Is writing to a SQL database slower than reading?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a 10MB file (blob) to a database using 64KB per iteration. However,  this takes nearly twice the time than it does reading the same file out of the database, is this normal that reading a database is faster than writing to a database?

Thanks

Comment: Is writing a book faster than reading it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, writing is normally slower than reading. When only reading from the database it doesn't have to bother with things like:

- Lock rows/pages/etc (Depending on isolation level)
- Allocate more space in the datafile
- Add rows to the transaction log
- Flush data to disk
- Update indexes
- Perform integrity checks

And so on. Reading is just reading straight from the disk, or possibly just return cached data from RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other info i would say that its because of your transaction isolation scope... Another guess is that your table is so large and your clustered index is affecting the whole operation here...

A more direct answer is: it is possible and happens more often than you think... as explained above the cluster index and locks can have a major impact on it because:

- Cluster index dictates the physical order of your data in the disk. Depending on the "key" (not your primary key, but the key of the index... yes they can be different) by inserting a file you are forcing a huge cascade changing
- If you use something like table lock and other operations are happening at the time of your insert, your statement will have to wait for those to complete...